# Space and time complexities, in Big O notation, for the JBIG compression algorithms?

Tags: performance

What are the computational complexities of JBIG lossless compression algorithm in Big O notation?

Answer (score 0):

Searching the internet, I see that there are a number of variants of JBIG, but [this paper suggests](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~dtompkin/papers/sc29wg1-n1014.pdf) O(image_size) or O(image_size+num_symbols) for the Soft Pattern Matching algorithm. Furthermore, [this paper states](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.5.4839&rep=rep1&type=pdf):

> The time complexity of the sequential algorithm (JBIG) is O(N).